# Apple Push Notifications ,How we get the alerts

Tags: objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Working with APNS(Apple Push Notifications)after creating the .cer, AppID and .p12. How Create the .PEM File. After Creating .PEM File what are the necessary steps i have to follow to get APNS Alerts  in My App. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's your question exactly, but an excellent tutorial for working with APNS: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

It's a little bit older older, but should still be correct. There are a lot of other very good tutorials on that page too!